# Questions on Apache Spark Internals - RDDs

Tags: apache-spark

I have a couple of questions about Spark internals, specifically RDDs. Based on what's in the docs, the lineage graphs of RDDs are DAG structures.

1. Are they persisted anywhere ? Is the 'golden copy' what is maintained by the driver program on the master node of the cluster ?

I have read documentation that states that the driver program sends off tasks
to the executors on worker nodes for processing.

2. What do these tasks look like ? Do they consist of an RDD object along with information as to which partition of the data that will be processed upon receipt of an action ?
3. What happens in the case where a node goes down and the data for a partition needs to be recomputed ? What are the exact sequence of steps that are executed ?

Any references to code or illustrative articles detailing the process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cover much of this in my Pluralsight course (https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/apache-spark-fundamentals). Specifically, in Spark Core: Part 1; section What is an RDD. Feel free to check it out and see if that resolves some of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do my best to answer your questions.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/file")
val rdd2 = rdd.map(line => line...)
val rdd3 = rdd2.filter(x => x...)
rdd3.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output")
```

I've created an rdd called "rdd".  In reality, this RDD is just a set of instructions on how to access data from a data source, like the HDFS.  I've then created "rdd2" by taking "rdd" and mapping it through some function, and same for "rdd3".  What I'm doing here is building a lineage.  Spark has two operations that it can apply to data: Transformations and Actions.  Transformations take an existing RDD and return a new RDD.  Actions take an RDD and return a result.  Spark doesn't process data until we call an action on a RDD. An action forces Spark to return a result, and this process the data.  There is no "golden copy."

In the first line of code, we're telling spark, if an action is performed on "rdd", then read the file from the HDFS.  In the second line of code, we're telling spark, if an action is called on "rdd2" read the file from HDFS then apply some transformation to it.  We're applying a transformation to "rdd" to get to "rdd2".  What this is doing is building a lineage, or recipe for processing this data.  In the third line of code, we're building up the lineage even more by saying, take what ever has already done to "rdd2" and then apply a filter to it.

saveAsTextFile is an action telling Spark to save "rdd3" somewhere.

When Spark is processing the data, its being streamed through these transformations, so its being read from HDFS, a function is applied to the data, then a filter is applied.  RDD's don't physically exist, they're just a set of instructions on how to process/access the data.

These function's we're applying to the data are in the form of tasks.  When a task is executed, Spark is passing the information required to process the data to a worker node.  The only thing contained in this task is what to do to the data.  So in our case, what ever is in the map and filter will be sent in the form of a task to a worker node.  The worker node will take these instructions and apply them to the data.  Each worker will work on a block of data at a time, so if the file we specified in sc.textFile is composed of 4 blocks in the HDFS, then there will be 4 tasks, one for each block of data in the HDFS

In the case a worker node goes down while processing the data, all tasks currently assigned to the worker will be reassigned to another worker.

Comment: This is somewhat helpful, in that it emphasizes the nature of an RDD as a set of instructions for performing transformations and actions on the data. I guess what I am trying to nail down is whether the driver program maintains the 'master/golden copy' of these instructions/RDD such that when a worker goes down, and the data that was supposed to be processed by that worked needs to reprocessed, the driver resends the RDD to another worker node. I assume that this is the case. What would this look like ? Something like 
`executor.execute(<RDD>, <partition_number>)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to look directly at the source code. Specifically, this line in 
*core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala*
seems to answer my question #2 above:

```
/**
 * :: DeveloperApi ::
 * Implemented by subclasses to compute a given partition.
 */
@DeveloperApi
def compute(split: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[T]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the example for mapping between MapReduce to Spark , this will help you in visualizing whats happening in Spark .

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-code-analysis/